# How to pivot string rows to multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2017

I have searched and tried and have not found the exact SQL code example I am looking for. I have multiple reps per an account (in rows) and need to spread these out into columns. I will have up to 3 for each account.

My source data looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+------+
| Account | Badge | Name |
+---------+-------+------+
|     123 |   456 | Bob  |
|     123 |   789 | John |
|     123 |   654 | Carl |
+---------+-------+------+
```

I need it to look like this:

```
+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| Account | Badge1 | Name1 | Badge2 | Name2 | Badge3 | Name3 |
+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|     123 |    456 | Bob   |    789 | John  |    654 | Carl  |
+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

If you DBMS support `ROW_NUMBER` and window function, make row number in a subquery, then do condition aggregate function make `pivot`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Account INT,
   Badge INT,
   Name VARCHAR(50)

);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,456,'Bob');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,789,'John');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,654,'Carl');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Account,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Badge end) Badge1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Name end) Name1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Badge end) Badge2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Name end) Name2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Badge end) Badge3,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Name end) Name3
FROM 
(
    SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Account) rn
    FROM T
) t1
GROUP BY Account
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c5568/1/0)**:

```
| Account | Badge1 | Name1 | Badge2 | Name2 | Badge3 | Name3 |
|---------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|
|     123 |    456 |   Bob |    789 |  John |    654 |  Carl |
```

Comment: I get
 
Account Badge1  Name1  Badge2  Name2  Badge3  Name3

  123    456      Bob    789    John    654    Carl
  968   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL

For the rest of the account numbers, the query returns NULL values.

Comment: @Gordy It work in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c5568/1 or you need to provide more sapmle data from you table

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c5568/2 you can add  `WHERE Account IS NOT NULL`